# Cant see the GUI in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I cannot see the unit and the platform in the game mode. I am trying to look for the answer but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: What are the transform position values of the camera and the object you want to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wall component had Cameras and that is why it bugged.